# Connection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver

Tags: mysql, php, lamp

I am newbie for Ubuntu and I was trying to run LAMP.

I installed MySQL, and PDO extensions. When I show the PHP config (with `phpinfo()`) it shows:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/apache2

Also I see *mysql* and *pdo_mysql* tables in the config output.

`locate pdo_mysql.so` giving: `/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so`

`locate mysql.so` giving:

```
/usr/lib/perl5/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysql.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so
/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/_mysql.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_mysql.so
```

in the `php.ini` file I enabled the extensions like this:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysql.so

extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so
```

But that does not help

Then I enabled

```
extension=mysql.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

still the same, no result,

after any changes I am restarting Apache2 with `service apache2 restart`

But still PHP can not locate PDO for opening connection.

So how can I get it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Ubuntu? Are you sure you need to add those lines to `php.ini?`

I have versions 10.03 and 11.10, and both are similar in that none of that is in `php.ini,` but is in the directory under that one, called `conf.d.`

In `conf.d/mysql.ini,` I have:

```
extension=mysql.so
```

In `conf.d/pdo.ini,` I have:

```
extension=pdo.so
```

In `conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini,` I have:

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

I don't have the newest version, and I also don't use any special LAMP stack, just the standard apps I installed separately, if that makes any difference.  But I never had any problems, and never had to explicitly install PDO that I can remember.

Comment: I found answer. In php.ini we need to point where is the extensions are located.
So I wrote in php.ini:

    extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php5/ext"


I created /usr/lib/php5/ext folder
then all .so files(mysql.so, pdo_mysql.so, ...) files i copied to there

then restart server with

    service apache2 restart

It worked.

So important thing is `extension_dir`

Make sure it is pointing to correct folder which has all .so files.

Comment: Well, mine isn't set up like that at all, but I guess as long as it works, that's what matters.  Mine just has `extension_dir = "./"`.